# Oracle 11G create loop and trigger though table bulk insert/update

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

Oracle 11G

Apex 4.2.6

below creates a 2 year work log for each engineer (:ENG_ID) APEX(form field). But now require to add a work log for a further 250-500 engineers. 
How can I loop though each :ENG_ID for existing staff and a trigger for new

```
merge INTO MD_TS_MAST D 
USING (SELECT :ENG_ID AS eng_id, 
          dt 
   FROM   ALL_DATES) s 
ON (D.eng_id= s.eng_id AND d.ms_date = s.dt) 
WHEN NOT matched THEN 
INSERT (D.eng_id, 
      D.ms_date) 
VALUES (s.eng_id, 
      s.dt);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is there a table somewhere that has all the ENG_ID's in it?

Comment: Yes eng table with eng_id and names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the ENG table has all the ENG_ID values and ALL_DATES has all the date values you could do something like:

```
MERGE INTO MD_TS_MAST d
  USING (SELECT e.ENG_ID,
                a.DT 
           FROM ENG e
           CROSS JOIN ALL_DATES a) s 
    ON (d.ENG_ID = s.ENG_ID AND
        d.MS_DATE = s.DT) 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (ENG_ID, 
            MS_DATE) 
    VALUES (s.ENG_ID, 
            s.DT);
```

Share and enjoy.

---

## EDIT

It sounds like what you're trying to do is add new rows to MD_TS_MAST when a new engineer is added to ENG. In that case an ON INSERT trigger on MD_TS_MAST would seem to be the best solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MD_TS_MAST_AI
  AFTER INSERT ON MD_TS_MAST
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO MD_TS_MAST d
    USING (SELECT :NEW.ENG_ID,
                  a.DT 
             FROM ALL_DATES a) s 
      ON (d.ENG_ID = s.ENG_ID AND
          d.MS_DATE = s.DT) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (ENG_ID, 
              MS_DATE) 
      VALUES (s.ENG_ID, 
              s.DT); 
END MD_TS_MAST_AI;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Absolutely perfect thank you very much. The second part would be to create a trigger which would fire the above script.Question been how can I turn the above script in to a trigger, which takes the last eng_id value.

Comment: @jasesykes - added trigger definition.